# WSO2 API 2.2.0 - API runtime call redirection

Tags: wso2, redirect, wso2-api-manager

How to redirect an API Call received by WSO2 API Manager to another API also running in the same server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand well your problem.

Why not, simply, in the new API declare the endpoints pointing old one?

If you want a more performant solution, create a custom sequence in the new one, with a call to the old.

Comment: Thanks Sourcerer.

In regards with routing the message - I completely agree and have used the same approach. In this approach - analytics out of the box indicate that there are 2 inbound calls. In reality its only one call. Hence, looking for re-direction

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As @Sourcerer has mentioned you can add mediation extension using custom mediation sequences. Have a look at https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Adding+Mediation+Extensions